# Java nested class visibility rules

Tags: java

Is there a less cumbersome way to access field `n` of object `other` below?

```
public class NestedVisibility
{
    private int n = 42;

    public static class B extends NestedVisibility {
        public void foo(NestedVisibility guest) {
            super.n = 0; // OK
            guest.n = 0; // OK

            B other = new B();
            other.n = 0; // Compile-time error. Weird!
            ((NestedVisibility)other).n = 0; // OK
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't it odd that I have to do more work to access a private field of `other` than a private field of `guest`?

Comment: The less cumbersome way might be to not write such weird code.

Comment: No it's not odd. The `private` modifier means that it's accessible only inside the **class**. Not inside the **instance**, but class. This allows two instances of the same class to access each other's private properties.

Comment: A static inner class extending the outer class, gives some headaches .

Comment: what are you trying to do? maybe we can help you come up with a construct which doesn't involve inner extending classes

Comment: @marco you want to use encapsulation. I provided an answer explaining the various things that are going on in your code and how to change it to answer your question. In general, You do not want to directly access values from other objects unless there is a need to bypass encapsulation which still is a bad idea because there are design patterns and OOP patterns that can help you avoid needing to bypass it.

Comment: @Thatalent I appreciate your perfectly reasonable answer below, but I must add that bypassing encapsulation is exactly one of the two reasons why static inner classes exist (the other being hiding a class).

Comment: I guess the compiler is being safe. Since `other` is of type `B`, and you're inside class `B`, `other.n` looks like it might be a private member of class `B`. There is nothing to stop `B` having a private member with the same name as a private member in its superclass. So letting you access the `NestedVisibility::n` via `other.n` would be wrong behaviour — you would be accessing the wrong variable. (Whereas if If you cast `other` to a `NestedVisibility` there is no possible ambiguity.)

Comment: @Marco I understand your point, if that is what you are trying to do then it would be better to not extend the outer class for the nested static class. The main reasons being that there is no need for inherit members of the outer class when you already have access to them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Private variables are not inherited by extending classes. You can access them through getters and setters that are inherited by the parent class.

This is your code rewritten to follow that:

```
public class NestedVisibility
{
    private int n = 42;

    public int getN(){
        return this.n;
    }

    public void setN(int n){
        this.n = n;
    }

    public static class B extends NestedVisibility {
        public void foo(NestedVisibility guest) {
            super.n = 0; // OK
            guest.n = 0; // OK

            B other = new B();
            other.setN(0);
            console.log(other.getN());
        }
    }
}
```

So basically `class B` does not have a `field n` but it's super does. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549775/using-a-private-variable-in-a-inherited-class-java) has a lot more information on that, plus there's lots of random blogs in the interwebs about it.

You can access the private variable from the nested class though. As in, if you make an object whose type is `NestedVisibility` (not extend) then you can directly access it within a nested class like the following:

```
public class NestedVisibility
{
    private int n = 42;

    public static class B extends NestedVisibility {
        public void foo(NestedVisibility guest) {
            super.n = 0; // OK
            guest.n = 0; // OK

            NestedVisibility other = new NestedVisibility();
            other.n = 0; //OK
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

> **Private** scope variables, are visible only to the class to which they belong.

If you expect the class to be extended and want to grant an access to the class variable, you should declare it with a **protected** scope.

```
public class NestedVisibility
{
  protected int n = 42;

  public static class B extends NestedVisibility {
    public void foo(NestedVisibility guest) {
      super.n = 0; // OK
      guest.n = 0; // OK

      B other = new B();
      other.n = 0; // now is OK
      ((NestedVisibility)other).n = 0; // OK
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, according to the JLS 6.6.1: "A private class member or constructor is accessible only within the body of the top level class that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor." Class B is within the body of NestedVisibility.

Comment: @Marco The access is available, as long as the NestedVisibility type is used. Once you start using extended class type, the private scope rule applies.